# How to configure NODE_OPTIONS variable in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, webpack

I am trying to build a react project in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.5.
While building I got an error,

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported MyReact Error   0
```

I know that error is caused because I am using Node 18.14.2 and the old OpenSSL version.
The workaround for that is setting up the NODE_OPTIONS variable like,

```
$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"
```

My question is how can I set that variable in Visual Studio so that the build is successful?

[image]

This is how my scripts portion looks,

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose --colors",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci --watchAll=false --colors --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --coverage --coverageReporters=cobertura --coverageThreshold '{}'",
    "test:coverage": "jest --verbose --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "test-debug": "node --inspect-brk --inspect ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest -i",
    "start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --mode development --open\" \"npm:stubby\"",
    "start:iis": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --iis",
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --progress --mode production --dev",
    "build:prod": "lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production",
    "lint": "eslint --cache --format codeframe --ext mjs,jsx,js src",
    "add-locale": "lingui add-locale",
    "extract": "lingui extract",
    "compile": "lingui compile",
    "stubby": "stubby --data stubs/stubby.yaml --watch"
  },
```

How should I update NODE_OPTIONS here?

UPDATE:

my .njsproj file,

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <Name>MyReact</Name>
    <RootNamespace>MyReact</RootNamespace>
    <NpmInstallStampFile>node_modules/.install-stamp</NpmInstallStampFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>333a402b-7769-4bfe-bbd0-e516bafafecf</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome>.</ProjectHome>
    <StartupFile>server.js</StartupFile>
    <SearchPath>
    </SearchPath>
    <WorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</WorkingDirectory>
    <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MyCtrl</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <NodejsPort>1337</NodejsPort>
    <StartWebBrowser>true</StartWebBrowser>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="package.json" />
    <Content Include="README.md" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:48022/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>True</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>http://localhost:1337</CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}" User="">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>False</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>False</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Deleting folder $(OutputPath)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NodeCheck">
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
  </Target>
  <!-- Run npm ci when package-lock.json is newer than $(NpmInstallStampFile), which contains the timestamp of last run -->
  <Target Name="NpmCIIncremental" Inputs="package-lock.json" Outputs="$(NpmInstallStampFile)">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm' because package-lock.json is newer. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm clean-install" />
    <Touch Files="$(NpmInstallStampFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NpmCI">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm clean-install" />
    <Touch Files="$(NpmInstallStampFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildReact">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Building React components..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:prod" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="NodeCheck;NpmCIIncremental;BuildReact">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;NodeCheck;NpmCI;BuildReact">
  </Target>
</Project>
```

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <Name>MyReact</Name>
    <RootNamespace>MyReact</RootNamespace>
    <NpmInstallStampFile>node_modules/.install-stamp</NpmInstallStampFile>
<!-- etc -->
    <Environment>NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider</Environment>
    <!-- etc -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>333a402b-7769-4bfe-bbd0-e516bafafecf</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectHome>.</ProjectHome>
    <StartupFile>server.js</StartupFile>
    <SearchPath>
    </SearchPath>
    <WorkingDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</WorkingDirectory>
    <OutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\MyCtrl</OutputPath>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AF33F2E-1136-4D97-BBB7-1795711AC8B8};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{9092AA53-FB77-4645-B42D-1CCCA6BD08BD}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <NodejsPort>1337</NodejsPort>
    <StartWebBrowser>true</StartWebBrowser>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="package.json" />
    <Content Include="README.md" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Node.js Tools\Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:48022/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>True</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>http://localhost:1337</CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}" User="">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>False</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>False</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Deleting folder $(OutputPath)" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NodeCheck">
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
  </Target>
  <!-- Run npm ci when package-lock.json is newer than $(NpmInstallStampFile), which contains the timestamp of last run -->
  <Target Name="NpmCIIncremental" Inputs="package-lock.json" Outputs="$(NpmInstallStampFile)">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm' because package-lock.json is newer. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm clean-install" />
    <Touch Files="$(NpmInstallStampFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NpmCI">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm clean-install" />
    <Touch Files="$(NpmInstallStampFile)" AlwaysCreate="true" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildReact">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Building React components..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:prod" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="NodeCheck;NpmCIIncremental;BuildReact">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;NodeCheck;NpmCI;BuildReact">
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: How is your Build process defined? Exactly what VS project type are you using?

Comment: My project file type is `.njsproj`

Comment: Edited question to include scripts portion from my package.json

Comment: [According to this **old** commit to VS's NodeJS Tooling from 2014](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/commit/6f9d0e55f56cb93d4a4c22e12ec6a8fc6fd31c1d) you should be able to specify environment-variables for Node/npm/etc via the `<Environment>`  MSBuild property in your `.njsproj` file - but I don't know if things have changed since 2014 when this commit was made.

Comment: Hmm, the `NodeProjectProperty.Environment` property [is still defined in the current repo's HEAD](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/blob/108142c5157fd0a0a8265c96d6a76f90fb173094/Nodejs/Product/Nodejs/NodejsConstants.cs#L102), so I assume it should still work...

Comment: Hmm, I added .njsproj file, can I point to where should I add this? Is it `<Environement>NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"</Environment>`

Answer (score 1):

- Visual Studio uses MSBuild for most project-types, including `.njsproj` projects.

  - I won't explain how MSBuild itself works, but remember that MSBuild doesn't replace your own Node projects' existing command-line build system: instead it sets-up an environment within which `node`, `npm`, etc will run, and then runs those build scripts.
- MSBuild projects are complicated beasts, but two main concepts are "properties" and "items".

  - MSBuild Properties are defined by `<PropertyGroup>`'s child elements in your root `<Project>` element. These generally control or refer to compiler options/switches and MSBuild's internal options. Element names are entirely free-form.
  - MSBuild Items are defined by XML element children of `<ItemGroup>` elements and generally refer to individual files. The element names generally refer to the file's *build action*, such as `<Compile>`, `<Content>`, `<None>`, and so on.
- In this case, the *Visual Studio Tools for Node* tooling defines two separate MSBuild properties for setting environment variables in the shell environment that it runs `node.exe` in: `<EnvironmentVariables>` and `<Environment>`.

  - [Since 2014, you should use the `<Environment>` property to specify environment-variables](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/commit/6f9d0e55f56cb93d4a4c22e12ec6a8fc6fd31c1d). Environment variables are defined as `name=value` and separated by newline characters directly in the `.njsproj` file,

    - *Do not* use the older `<EnvironmentVariables>` property, which has limitations (e.g. you can't use semicolons in it).
- In your case, locate the a suitable `<PropertyGroup>` in your `.njsproj` file: you may see multiple `<PropertyGroup>` elements with different `condition=""` attributes - you can also add a new `<PropertyGroup>` element if necessary. So you should have something like this:

```xml
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <Name>MyReact</Name>
    <RootNamespace>MyReact</RootNamespace>
    <NpmInstallStampFile>node_modules/.install-stamp</NpmInstallStampFile>
    <!-- etc -->
    <Environment>NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider</Environment>
    <!-- etc -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- etc -->
</Project>
```

For additional variables, use newlines, e.g.:

```xml
<Project etc>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- etc -->
    <Environment>NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
anotherVariable=goeshere
third=value
and=so-on</Environment>
    <!-- etc -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It's unclear what you should do if you need to include a `\r\n` *within* an environment-variable, though.

---

**Warning:** Note that MSBuild properties can be re-defined in other MSBuilder `.targets` and `.props` files, in which case your `<Environment>` property *may* be reset. So when setting MSBuild properties consider if you want to *append* or even *wrap* a property's value instead of replacing it - [in which case use MSBuild's `$()` syntax within the property-element to get the current property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157714/how-to-append-conditional-compilation-symbols-in-project-properties-with-msbuild).

For example, if you want to preserve any defined `<Environment>` from elsewhere in your project, and simply want to *add* more environment-variables, do this:

```xml
<Environment>$(Environment)
NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider</Environment>
```

Note that this appends to the entire MSBuild property - it doesn't specifically allow you to append to a specific environment-variable, in which case you'll need to use [MSBuild's string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022), which gets gnarly so I won't go into detail on that here.

Comment: Still got the same error! Update .njsproj file. Running build runs `npm run build:prod` for me. then it resulted into same `     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
    library: 'digital envelope routines',
    reason: 'unsupported',
    code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
  }
  Node.js v18.14.2`

Comment: @tRuEsAtM What happens if you run `msbuild` from the command-line to build your project? Can you inspect the `node.exe` process in `ProcExp.exe` when it runs in a build to see what its actual environment-variables are?

Comment: From command line, powershell, it works fine.

Comment: ...by running `msbuild YourProject.njsproj` _with_ the added `<Environment>` element, right?

Comment: Right, updated the project file and right click ran build in Visual Studio, build failed. But, for the same, if I ran it in command line, or powershell, where I have explicitly set the env variable, it is successful.

Comment: Please post your _current_ `njsproj` file in your question.

Comment: Added updated njsproj

Comment: @tRuEsAtM I'll admit I'm stumped. I don't know why it's not working for you. I suggest you post an Issue in the Node-tools-for-VS GitHub though.

Comment: Added screenshots from process explorer.

Comment: I updated my package.json with ```    "build:dev": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && webpack --progress --mode production --dev",
    "build:prod": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && lingui add-locale en && lingui extract --clean && lingui compile && webpack --mode production",``` And that fixed it. Don't know why njsproj file update fails :(